# Create nested records REST API - errorCode "INVALID FIELD"

Tags: rest-api, json, master-detail

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_create.htm) here is what my body looks like for the request.

I'm trying to create one parent (SEO__CSEO_Survey__c) and then one child (SEO__CSEO_Survey_Question__c) in a master-detail relationship.

```
{
"records":[{
    "attributes":{"type":"SEO__CSEO_Survey__c","referenceId":"survey"},
    "Name":null,
    "SEO__Survey_Welcome_Heading__c":null,
    "SEO__Welcome_Text__c":"Test444",
    "SEO__CSEO_Survey_Question__c":{
        "records": [{
           "SEO__Order__c":null,
           "SEO__Question__c":"q1",
           "attributes":{"type":"SEO__CSEO_Survey_Question__c","referenceId":"question0"}
        }]
     }
}]
}
```

The error

> [
>     {
>       "message": "No such column 'SEO__CSEO_Survey_Question__c' on sobject of type SEO__CSEO_Survey__c",
>       "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
>     }
>   ]

What I don't understand from the docs is on line 9 of the example code. The example uses "Contacts", as if that was a field on Account, which it is not, correct?

Instead of naming my key `SEO__CSEO_Survey_Question__c`, what should it be?

Update: Solved thanks to Adrian. Here is a screenshot of my relationship if someone has a problem understanding the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the child relationship name, you can use this script:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.SEO__CSEO_Survey__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == SEO__CSEO_Survey_Question__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

The relationship name should be printed exactly as you need to specify it. Usually it's plural, and always ends in `__r` for custom relationships. So the expected value would be: `SEO__CSEO_Survey_Questions__r`.

Comment: I've gone ahead and [moved this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56274/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-create-nested-records-rest-api-errorcode).